# Specify id label for data loaded from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is it possible to load fully custom set of data into select2? I mean I can customize the option text property, can I also do it for id?

The code below works perfect

```
var dummy = [
    { id: 1, Name: "opt1" },
    { id: 2, Name: "opt2" }
];

$("#myselect").select2({
    data: { results: dummy, text: "Name" },
    formatSelection: function (item) { return item.Name; },
    formatResult: function (item) { return item.Name }
});
```

However, my data incoming has the id property in caps. It surely would be possible for me to rename these objects' properties iterating through the received data set, yet the amount of data is pretty large and I certainly do not want to slow this simple load down. I'd also love to have these object properties stay.

Long story short, my data is like

```
var dummy = [
    { ID: 1, Name: "opt1" },
    { ID: 2, Name: "opt2" }
 ];
```

Is it possible to define an alternate id key?

Comment: Actually it's kind of external server data. Anyway while looking on options available I found the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, there is an option called `id`

> Function used to get the id from the choice object or a string
>   representing the key under which the id is stored.

```
$("#myselect").select2({
    id: 'ID',
    data: { results: dummy, text: "Name" },
    formatSelection: function (item) { return item.Name; },
    formatResult: function (item) { return item.Name }
});
```

Comment: It's right. I was looking at the wrong sections of the select2 docs. At first I tried to put this into `data` object which was more intuitive to me, still this looks nice. Thank you very much